# ReactJS react-grid-layout toggle static property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draggable, react-grid-layout

I've been learning React for a couple of days, this time I'm trying to create a grid of draggable widgets, and I found this library on github: [react-grid-layout](https://github.com/STRML/react-grid-layout) which does that.

This time, I'm trying to toggle draggable or `static` property when clicking on a `button` but I'm having some troubles doing so.

This is my `App.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {InputText} from 'primereact/components/inputtext/InputText';
import GridLayout from 'react-grid-layout';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        var layout = [
            {i: 'a', x: 0, y: 0, w: 10, h: 4},
            {i: 'b', x: 1, y: 0, w: 3, h: 2},
            {i: 'c', x: 4, y: 0, w: 1, h: 2}
        ];
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <button onClick={this.toggleStatic (layout)}>Enable</button>
                <GridLayout className="layout" layout={layout} cols={30} rowHeight={30} width={1200} onDragStop={this.onDragStop}>
                    <div key="a">a</div>
                    <div key="b">b</div>
                    <div key="c">c</div>
                </GridLayout>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }

    toggleStatic(layout) {
        console.log('Layout', layout);
    }

    onDragStop(layout) {
        layout[0].static = true;
        console.log(layout);
    }
}

export default App;
```

My `index.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import 'react-grid-layout/css/styles.css';
import 'react-resizable/css/styles.css';
import 'primereact/resources/themes/omega/theme.css';
import 'primereact/resources/primereact.min.css';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

And my `index.css`:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.react-grid-item:not(.react-grid-placeholder) {
    background-color: #ccc;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.layout {
    background-color: #333;
}

.title {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

If I check my console, right after reloading the page I get my `layout` logged into it, before any click:

```
Layout […]
​0: Object { i: "a", x: 0, y: 0, … }
1: Object { i: "b", x: 1, y: 0, … }    ​
2: Object { i: "c", x: 4, y: 0, … }    ​
length: 3
__proto__: Array []
```

But if I change my `button` to:

```
<button onClick={this.toggleStatic}>Enable</button>
```

i.e. removing the parameter `layout` from it, I get this output in the console:

```
Layout Proxy
    <target>: Object { … }
    <handler>: Object { … }
```

Right now, my code changes `static` of first widget to `true` when any component is dragged, I'm trying to change it for all of then on a button click.

I found this post on the library's issues: [Assign static dinamically/programatically](https://github.com/STRML/react-grid-layout/issues/327), but they're using `react-redux`.

I found them using this as well:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    ...state.dashboard.asMutable()
  };
};
```

But I'm not sure what does that does.

Any suggestion to at least receive the `layout` var into the `toggleStatic` might be enough for me for this matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{this.toggleStatic (layout)}` will trigger the function on `render` not `onClick`, so you gotta change:

```
<button onClick={this.toggleStatic (layout)}>Enable</button>
```

to:

```
<button onClick={() => this.toggleStatic(layout)}>Enable</button>
```

Then when you click on the button you get the layout.

Add layout in `state`:

```
// ...
class App extends Component {
    state = {
         layout: [
            {i: 'a', x: 0, y: 0, w: 10, h: 4},
            {i: 'b', x: 1, y: 0, w: 3, h: 2},
            {i: 'c', x: 4, y: 0, w: 1, h: 2}
         ]
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <button onClick={() => this.toggleStatic(this.state.layout)}>Enable</button>
                <GridLayout className="layout" layout={this.state.layout} cols={30} rowHeight={30} width={1200} onDragStop={this.onDragStop}>
                    <div key="a">a</div>
                    <div key="b">b</div>
                    <div key="c">c</div>
                </GridLayout>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }

// ...
```

Then in `toggleStatic` function do something like:

```
toggleStatic(layout){
    var newLayout = layout.map(l => {
           return {...l, static: !l.static || true}
    })
    this.setState({
        layout: newLayout
    })
}
```

Comment: You're right, this actually sends the `layout` to my method but I discovered it's a different `layout` from the one I want to update, as my objects aren't being affected at all by the changes made there...

Comment: I am getting `Line 18:  'layout' is not defined  no-undef`; `Line 18` is where `<button...` is

Comment: My bad, that should be `this.state.layout`, I edited the anwser.

Comment: May I know what the `...l` does? It's the second time I see it and would like to learn more about. More specifically the 3 dots

Comment: Here it means all arguments in object, you just wanna change the `static` argument of object `l`, so you keep the rest unchanged with `...l` and set `static` new value.